# No Method called on back press from some other app

Tags: android, android-intent

I have share button in my app and pressing it works fine. But on back press from app (like "Whatsapp", "gmail" etc.) my app hangs with black screen. The share button is in navigation drawer layout. I debugged the code and none of the methods are being called on back press from the other app.

Activity Code (not full activity but some relevant methods):

```
    public class HomeActivity extends Activity
            implements View.OnClickListener, AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
sideMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
mSideMenuListAdapter = new SideMenuListAdapter(this, mDrawerLayout);
sideMenu.setAdapter(mSideMenuListAdapter);
```

Code in my adapter:

```
holder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
Intent share = new Intent();
share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("text/plain");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "***");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "***"));
share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
              Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share link!"));
}
});
```

On Click of share button below methods are called in my activity in sequence :

```
@Override
    public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
        super.startActivity(intent);
    }

@Override
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }

 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

On Whatsapp click below method is called

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }
```

Now when I press back button from whatsapp, none of the method is invoked. Just the blank screen appears and app hangs. In debug mode though, I get my screen layout (which was before pressing whatsapp button) but the screen is totally inactive. The only way to come out is killing the app.

I have tried number of things but nothing see to be working. Please help.

Comment: Since you call `startActivityForResult()`, the method that should be called when you go back to your application is `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`

Comment: He is not calling `startActivityForResult` but `startActivity`

Comment: @NicolasSimon Thanks. Checked by putting break point on onActivityResult. Even that method isn't being called.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking `resultCode` in `onActivityResult` method

use below code it will work fine

```
if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){
//do your task here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already coded a suggested but that isn't working.

Comment: @gaurav you change `startActivity` to `startActivityForResult` then it will work for you.. `mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share link!"));`